# Dynamic and lazy Routing in Angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

let me give you brief explanation of what I am trying to implement

In Angular project firstly login module loads after successful login I fetch the user role and user-data against that valid-user from API , In that user-data there is sidebar related data from which I have to create the Dynamic sidebar on UI and register routes against that sidebar
the JSON of sidebar is

```
sidebarData = [
      { routingPath:"createJob",
        path:"src/modules/create-job/create-job",
        moduleName:"CreateJobModule"
      },
      { routingPath:"save-job",
        path:"/src/modules/save-job/save-job",
        moduleName:"SaveJobModule"
      },
      { routingPath:"report-dashboard",
        path:"/src/modules/report-dashboard/report-dashboard",
        moduleName:"ReportDashboardModule"
      }
    ]

sidebarData.forEach((nav:any) =>
    {   
      let route : Routes = [
    { path:nav.routingPath,
       loadChildren:()=> import('src/modules/create-job/create- 
       job.module').then(x=>x.CreateJobModule)},
       this.router.resetConfig(route); 
   })
```

HTML Part

```
    <button *ngFor="let nav of sidebarData" routerLink="{{nav.routingPath}}"> {{nav.moduleName}} </button>
</div>
```

I have to implement this lazy Loading Dynamically can anyone help me with this
If you need more information you can ask

Comment: Maybe you should use CanLoad guard and check if user has permissions to load specific module?

Comment: I am getting the modules which are permitted to the user-role so no need to check with canLoad guard , I need the module import and registration in route part

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the CanLoad route guards. To generate a template:

```
ng g guard user-permissions
```

Within this guard you can inject a service with access to the user permissions. This combined with the data property on the lazy routes to add a key value pair to match up with user permissions. Place this guard on each of these routes and it will dynamically lazy load the appropriate routes.

```
const routes = [
  {
    ...,
    data: {
      [userPermissionsKey]: "valueForThisRoute"
    },
    canLoad: [UserPermissionsGuard]
  },
  ...
];
```

If you extract the filtering logic from the guard to another service also - you could use the exact same filtering logic for both your side menu, and guard, for the routes.

Here's some extra info on canLoad:
https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad

Hope this helps!

Comment: sidebarData.forEach((nav:any) =>
    {   
      let route : Routes = [
    { path:nav.routingPath,
       loadChildren:()=> import('src/modules/create-job/create- 
       job.module').then(x=>x.CreateJobModule)},
       this.router.resetConfig(route); 
   }) in above code can you explain  what should I use insted of " createJobModule "  in .then(x=>x.CreateJobModule)  because i am getting module name also from config

Comment: Can you clarify where this config is stored/how it is accessed?

Comment: config is stored in datastore and json format of that config is [
      { routingPath:"createJob",
        path:"src/modules/create-job/create-job",
        moduleName:"CreateJobModule"
      },
      { routingPath:"save-job",
        path:"/src/modules/save-job/save-job",
        moduleName:"SaveJobModule"
      },
      { routingPath:"report-dashboard",
        path:"/src/modules/report-dashboard/report-dashboard",
        moduleName:"ReportDashboardModule"
      }
    ]  config is received after valid login and i haev to implement complete routing with received config

Comment: I think the issue you will have here is, to my knowledge, all the lazy modules need to be known at build time. If they aren't known at build time, they would not be included at in the build (as lazy modules or not).

Comment: Is there any way to implement dynamic and lazy modules with routes ??